# keeping text size proportion in ggplots using marrangeGrob()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a shiny app that produce a lot of plots at the same time.
At the end of the plotting, the user can export all the plots in a single pfd file.

However, Im implementing a popup box, where the user can select how many of those plots per page want to export.
The code for the plotting, buttons and exporting is working fine, however when the used want to export a lot of plots together (64, 8x8) all the font sizes in my code are too big and they look terrible in the pdf.
The code for my plot is as follows:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=time,y=distance,color=color)) +
  geom_point(na.rm=TRUE,size=1.2)+geom_line(linewidth=.7) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=yerror-stddev,ymax=yerror+stddev),
                width=0.05,linewidth=0.1,color="black") +
  xlab("time (sec)")+
  ylab("meters (m)")+
  ggtitle(title)+
  theme_bw()+
  expand_limits(y = 0)+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 5), 
        axis.text=element_text(size=8),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 4),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5,size=11),
        legend.position=c(0.87, 0.26),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white",color="gray"))
```

and to export the plots I use:

```
ggsave(marrangeGrob(alluplots, nrow=input$rows, ncol=input$columns),
       width = 8.5, height = 11)
```

Is there a way to keep the same proportion for all fonts in my plot no matter how many plots are exported in the same page?

Comment: What about setting the font size for all plots to say 8 points: `library(ggplot2) theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 8)) ggplot(....`.

Comment: Perhaps you can calculate the desired font size based on the `nrow` / `ncol` inputs & apply that theme to all your plots? Also, I'd be careful about giving users free rein regarding how many plots to fit into one page, as readability can quickly become problematic.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I did create a variable that depends of # rows and columns. And then calculate the font size using it. Now it's working. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do is is to calculate the font size depending on the number of rows and columns.
I created a variable depending on rows and columns that was later used for that.